# AzureMaps calculation distances by countries

Tags: azure-maps

Good afternon! How can i get a route summary for each country in the route? For example, I want to move from Ukraine to France. I get route from GetRouteDirections, the route runs through 4 countries, and i want to see - how many kilometers this route takes over each of the countries of the route

Answer (score 2):

Currently the Azure Maps routing service does not provide an option to return this information, although it is something being considered as a future feature. I have seen this question in the past with other mapping platforms, and there was nothing out of the box for this in those platforms either.

That said, if you want to achieve this today you can do the following:

- Get a set of country boundaries that are suitable for your users (if you have users in countries that have disputed borders, you will likely need several sets of country boundaries).
- Calculate a route and use path to create a line.
- Calculate the intersection of the line with each country boundary and then measure the length of the section of line that intersects.

I've done this as a proof of concept in the past using a set of GeoJSON country boundaries and the JavaScript topology suite (https://github.com/bjornharrtell/jsts). I haven't posted the code online as country borders are disputed in some regions and thus, any sample I put out there wouldn't work globally.

A global solution could be achieved by retrieving the country boundaries from Azure Maps, but you would need to retrieve the boundaries for all countries first, which would be a bit time consuming and generate a lot of transactions.